# Rails3 UJS response not evaluated

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, prototypejs

It gives me the creeps,i'm done, i need some help here, i reverted multiple times back but i can't find the error.

Simple controller (customers),a simple form for adding a customer via :remote => true and the controller does respond_to do |format| { format.js } . Works fine, renders my create.js.rjs template.

I work for a few hours without making any javascript changes or changes to my controllers or authorization etc.. and when i try it again it's not working anymore.

What i mean with not working: Controller gets called, record saved, all partials rendered. But no javascript evaluated, not even a simple alert(1) at the beginning of the file.

I tried with different prototype.js versions and different rails.js versions, but nothing helped. I hope someone has a clue about this or already experienced this.

It's not that i don't want to post code. But it won't help. Its basic code that works and, after some changes where i don't know what i really changed (some locales here, some css there, html templates from a completely different controller a bit..)..

Currently developing with: ruby 1.9.2, rails 3.0.3, prototype 1.7 RC3, rails.js from github.

Comment: comment out sections of your javascript until you find the section that has an error. You can also go back in your commits until you find the commit where it stopped working?

Comment: the problem is that, like i said, i can put a usual page.alert or alert in it and it is not working. i just saw that it is site-wide, for every ajax-call. but i try to figure it out..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

How stupid, I missed the part where the template naming changed. My application templace was named "application.rhtml". It worked until now. As it stopped to work, I changed it to "application.html.erb" and now it's working.